# append multiple numbers into a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, append

I have this column of numbers from a txt file that I want to append into a list:

```
18.0
13.0
10.0
12.0 
8.0
```

my code for placing all these numbers into a list is

```
    last_number_lis = []
    for numbers_to_put_in in (path/to/txt):
        last_number_lis.append(float(last_number))
    print last_number_lis
```

I want the list to look like

```
[18.0,13.0,10.0,12.0,8.0]
```

but instead, when running the code, it shows

```
[18.0]
[13.0]
[10.0] 
[12.0]
[8.0]
```

Is there any way that all the number can be in one line. Later on, I would like to add all the numbers up. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: can you post the entire code  ?

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: @Dadep I posted part of the code since the total script has over 200 lines.

Comment: you reading values from a `.txt` file ? it's one column with values ?

Comment: see edit in my post

Comment: @SlyingTwilight What we meant was to post the code that also included what `last_number_lis` was and how `last_number` was taken in, as these would affect the answer. But I see you edited the question in this way, so it looks like you got the message :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `append` a list just like :

```
>>> list=[]
>>> list.append(18.0)
>>> list.append(13.0)
>>> list.append(10.0)
>>> list
[18.0, 13.0, 10.0]
```

but depend where your number are coming from ...

for example with input in terminal :

```
>>> list=[]
>>> t=input("type a number to append the list : ")
type a number to append the list : 12.45
>>> list.append(float(t))
>>> t=input("type a number to append the list : ")
type a number to append the list : 15.098
>>> list.append(float(t))
>>> list
[12.45, 15.098]
```

or reading from file :

```
>>> list=[]
>>> with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
...     for i in infile:
...             list.append(float(i))
... 
>>> list
[13.189, 18.8, 15.156, 11.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is from a `.txt` file you would have to do the `readline()` method,

You could do a for loop and loop through the list of numbers (you never know how many numbers you may be given and might as well let the loop handle it,

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    elemts = f.readlines()
    elemts = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

and then you'd want to loop through the file and add the elements in the list

```
last_number_list = []
for last_number in elements:
    last_number_list.append(float(last_number))
print last_number_list
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less compact but easy to read approach is

```
num_list = []
f = open('file.txt', 'r')   # open in read mode 'r'
lines = f.readlines() # read all lines in file
f.close()  # safe to close file now
for line in lines:
    num_list.append(float(line.strip()))
print num_list
```